# Prefect 2: What is the difference between a storage block and an infrastructure block?

Tags: prefect

I've been trying to utilise Prefect 2 for my team, and it seems quite powerful. However there are a few concepts that I dont quite fully understand around the infrastructure and blocks

What is the difference between a storage block and an infrastructure block? The docs mention that

> Storage blocks contain configuration for interacting with file storage such as a remote filesystem, AWS S3, and so on.
>
> Infrastructure blocks contain settings that agents use to stand up execution infrastructure for a flow run.

But when we deploy, how does this work? Say I have a local file storage, and want to run multiple flows with different python environments, would I create a different infrastructure for each flow and point them all to the same storage block?

Answer (score 3):

Yes exactly, your intuition is correct. Storage defines where your code lives (could be GitHub, S3, local path or even docker image path) and infrastructure block defines where to and how the flow run should be deployed - infrastructure could be a KubernetesJob, serverless container, etc.  We have some more concrete info [here on Discourse](https://discourse.prefect.io/t/prefect-deployments-faq-pdf/1467)